Endless indexing of point clouds in QGis
I am creating a Qgis plugin that processes point clouds. When creating a QgsPointCloudLayer object in Qgis, indexing of this layer begins. But this indexing reaches 100% and is not completed.
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        input = self.parameterAsPointCloudLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context).source()
        output = self.parameterAsFileOutput(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context)

        #processing point cloud
        #...

        # adding layer
        layer = QgsPointCloudLayer(output, "New layer", 'pdal')

        if not layer.isValid():
            feedback.pushInfo("invalid layer!")
        else:
            feedback.pushInfo("layer loaded!")
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

        return {self.name(): 0}

Endless indexing in Qgis
I was trying to specify the path to the files .las, .laz, .copc.laz, but the result was always the same - endless indexing. If you add this cloud point to Qgis manually (by dragging or layer - > add layer), then everything will work fine.
I tried to create a QgsPointCloudLayer in the Python console (which is inside Qgis) and it worked. But it doesn't work inside the plugin.
